# fftw Visual Studio 2010 compiled static library LNK2001 Error __imp_fftwf

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fftw

i successfully compiled a 64bit version of the fftw 3.3.4 library as a static library with the source code and the Visual Studio Solution from "fftw-3.3-libs-visual-studio-2010.zip".
Now i try to link to the static library in a project where i use the fftw.
During building/linking i get LNK2001 errors

```
Fehler  30  error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__imp_fftwf_malloc"
```

Sry, i have a german Visual Studio installation. Basically it says that there is a not resolved symbol named "__imp_fftwf_malloc". I get this error for all the fftw functions i am calling, and there is allways this "__imp_" in front of the function name.

I have linked against the library and /verbose:lib shows me that the library was searched successfully.
Does anybody have any clue where the problerm might be?

EDIT1:
I did a dumpbin on thee library i created and copied all the entries where fftw_malloc was mentioned, maybe this can help?

```
public symbol
A57BF4 fftwf_malloc
25B fftwf_malloc

Linker Directives
-----------------
/DEFAULTLIB:"libcpmtd"
/DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMTD"
/DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES"
/DEFAULTLIB:"VCOMPD"
/EXPORT:fftwf_malloc
/EXPORT:fftwf_free
/EXPORT:fftwf_alloc_real
/EXPORT:fftwf_alloc_complex

RELOCATIONS #2
                                            Symbol    Symbol
  Offset    Type              Applied To         Index     Name
 --------  ----------------  -----------------  --------  ------
 00000570  SECREL                     00000000         7  fftwf_malloc
 00000574  SECTION                        0000         7  fftwf_malloc
 000005C0  SECREL                     00000000         7  fftwf_malloc
 000005C4  SECTION                        0000         7  fftwf_malloc

RELOCATIONS #3
                                            Symbol    Symbol
 Offset    Type              Applied To         Index     Name
 --------  ----------------  -----------------  --------  ------
 00000024  REL32                      00000000         E  fftwf_kernel_malloc
 00000064  REL32                      00000000        1B  fftwf_kernel_free
 000000AB  REL32                      00000000         7  fftwf_malloc
 000000EB  REL32                      00000000         7  fftwf_malloc

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 00AA766F ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
001 00000000 SECT1  notype       Static       | .drectve
    Section length   B9, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
003 00000000 SECT2  notype       Static       | .debug$S
    Section length 1194, #relocs   10, #linenums    0, checksum        0
005 00000000 SECT3  notype       Static       | .text
    Section length   F5, #relocs    4, #linenums    0, checksum 50F0AACD
007 00000000 SECT3  notype ()    External     | fftwf_malloc
008 00000000 SECT4  notype       Static       | .pdata
    Section length   30, #relocs    C, #linenums    0, checksum BFE4C30B
00A 00000000 SECT4  notype       Static       | $pdata$fftwf_malloc
00B 00000000 SECT5  notype       Static       | .xdata
```

Comment: Are you sure you're linking with the single precision library (`fftwf`) rather than double precision (`fftw`) ?

Comment: I tried all combinations, just the single precission, the double precission and both libraries together.